# neovim can not find python correctly because of virtualenv or conda?

Tags: python, vim, virtualenv, conda, neovim

I install `YouCompleteMe` and `UltiSnips` plugins in my `neovim`. Normally, everything is ok.

But I am using [`MiniConda`](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/intro.html) in my python developing, `MiniConda` is something like `virtualenv`, I have a virtual python env called `parser`, when I activate this virtualenv with `source activate parser`, something is wrong:

```
YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires Vim compiled with Python 2.x support
UltiSnips requires py >= 2.7 or py3
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

so the problem is `neovim` can not find python properly, I am confused why `virtualenv` affect `neovim`?

Comment: I got the UltiSnips error message to go away by (re)installing the `neovim` package, inside the current environment, with `pip install neovim`.

Comment: Thank you @Alex. That is indeed the answer.

Answer (score 4):

As @Alex mentioned in comments `pip install neovim` solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If Neovim finds python on your `$PATH`, it assumes this is Python 2 (and likewise for python3 being treated as Python 3). If you start Neovim from a shell with an activated Conda env that uses Python 3, you're going to have problems because the conda env exposes a binary called python, but which is really 3 and not 2. Because of this, you will have to use the Neovim option of setting `g:python_host_prog` to point to a valid Python 2, into which you must also have pip installed the required neovim client.

Possible solution (I have tested myself using anaconda):

```
# neovim init.vim file cmd
# runs python3 for neovim from a specific env
# should resolve the need for neovim in each new python env when using nvim
# add the following to your init.vim file
let g:python3_host_prog = '/path/to/anaconda3/bin/python'
```

add this in your `.vimrc` or `ginit.vim` (neovim GUI configuration file).